# How does the cross-origin policy work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain, xss

This confuses me a lot. Let's say I have 2 tabs open in my browser, one on `http://aaa.com` and another on `http://bbb.com`.

Let's say I make a request

```
$ajax({
    method : 'POST',
    url : 'http://aaa.com/SomeAction',
    ... 
});
```

from the JavaScript console of my browser. The way I understand cross-origin policy is that the server only allows that request to happen if the JS console I typed it into was the one in the tab for `http://aaa.com`. But how does the server know that? Does my browser send it a header that tells it where the request is coming from?

Comment: You can open `Network` tab, select url of `$.ajax()` request, click `Headers` tab, scroll to `Request Headers` to review request and response headers for the request.

Comment: The server doesn’t have to know about anything – the _client_ is the one that enforces this policy. (Unless we’re are talking about CORS here, then the server of course has to play its part as well.)

Comment: @CBroe — Even with CORS, the server doesn't enforce the policy; it relaxes it.

Comment: @Quentin I didn’t say the server enforces it, only that it plays a part in it.

Answer (score 0):

> is that the server only allows that request to happen if the JS
>   console I typed it into was the one in the tab for `http://aaa.com`

Not true.

Nothing stops example.com from sending an AJAX request to example.org. The Same Origin Policy however will prevent example.com from reading the response returned.

The [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) is enforced in the client-side browser, not on the server.